# javascript mouse coordinates with canvas and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

well right now im trying to learn how to use the canvas tag on html, and im having trouble handling mouse events when i apply css to the document.

the issue starts when i move the div containing the canvas and center it on the page, the first poing of the canvas wouldnt be 0 because its centered and for some reason 0,0 would be the beginning of the screen and not the beginning of the canvas, which i found weird because im adding the event listener to the canvas directly.

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #42413C;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}
#divId {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color:#0099FF;
}
</style>

<script>
window.onload = function () {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');   
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    alert("lol");
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', hmd, false);

    function hmd(e) {
        alert ("x: " + e.clientX + "     y: " + e.clientY); 
    }

}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="divId">

<canvas height="300" width="800" id="canvasId" />

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

so i read somewhere that the issue was caused by the div, but when i tried to give css directly to the canvas tag it didnt work, so basically what i need to do, is to get that canvas centered or placed anywhere on the screen, but having its first pixel as 0,0.
adding a solution would be hard because its centering automatically, so i would need to know the user resolution to be able to calculate the offset so what im looking for is a way to do it simply with css or something.

Comment: Protip: use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging. :)

Comment: Protip #2: New code should use a *strict* doctype instead of transitional.  While it doesn't matter in this case, since older versions of IE don't support canvas, IE is known to act quite differently in `Quirks Mode.`

Comment: thanks jeremy j starcher, i actually knew that, just forgot about it when i made this sample code to show what my problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the coordinates relatively to the `canvas`, do this:

```
function hmd(e) {
    var rx = e.pageX, ry = e.pageY;
    rx -= canvas.offsetLeft;
    ry -= canvas.offsetTop;
    alert ("x: " + rx + "     y: " + ry); 
}
```

This assumes your `canvas` variable definition is global.

**Edit:** another method:

```
function hmd(e) {
    var rx, ry;
    if(e.offsetX) {
        rx = e.offsetX;
        ry = e.offsetY;
    }
    else if(e.layerX) {
        rx = e.layerX;
        ry = e.layerY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've been using for my latest experimentation. It works with damn near everything: Borders, paddings, position:fixed elements offsetting the HTML element, etc. It also works on all touch devices and even if the browser is zoomed.

http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/te8GQ/5/

```
var stylePaddingLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(can, undefined)['paddingLeft'], 10) || 0;
var stylePaddingTop = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(can, undefined)['paddingTop'], 10) || 0;
var styleBorderLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(can, undefined)['borderLeftWidth'], 10) || 0;
var styleBorderTop = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(can, undefined)['borderTopWidth'], 10) || 0;
var html = document.body.parentNode;
var htmlTop = html.offsetTop;
var htmlLeft = html.offsetLeft;

function getMouse(e) {
    var element = can,
        offsetX = 0,
        offsetY = 0,
        mx, my;

    // Compute the total offset
    if (element.offsetParent !== undefined) {
        do {
            offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
            offsetY += element.offsetTop;
        } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
    }

    // Add padding and border style widths to offset
    // Also add the <html> offsets in case there's a position:fixed bar
    offsetX += stylePaddingLeft + styleBorderLeft + htmlLeft;
    offsetY += stylePaddingTop + styleBorderTop + htmlTop;

    mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
    my = e.pageY - offsetY;

    // We return a simple javascript object (a hash) with x and y defined
    return {
        x: mx,
        y: my
    };
}
```

Comment: im going to have to read this code carefully to be able to understand it and actually use it, thanks a lot.